# New Raspberry Pi B+ not compatible with Noobs 1.4

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, hdmi, noobs, pi-b+

I've got an SD card I clone every time I buy new RPi B+ and I use it as a base system with all of the software I need pre-installed and configured. It's built on Noobs 1.4.x.

The problem occurred when I bought two new boards yesterday and like always inserted cloned SD card - but **RPi wasn't sending any signal over HDMI**.

So I copied fresh files of Noobs 1.4.x and tried to install from scratch - same result: no signal on HDMI.

But when I loaded Noobs 1.9.2 to SD card, everything worked and installation started normally.

I compared new boards with the old ones. They all are RPi Model B+ V1.2 (c)RPi 2014. The only difference I noticed is that new ones have **Elpida chip and old ones Samsung**.

So the question is - **why aren't they compatible**? Shouldn't RPis be compatible within the same version? And **what can I do to run my cloned SD card on those new boards**?

Comment: Have you kept the firmware updated on the old cards?  If you are not sure, check the modification dates with `stat`.  Running `sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt update` should do this (no sure if NOOBS complicates that), and even if the images are still wheezy based they should work with 2014 boards.  The Elpida vs. Samsung thing is the RAM, which is layered on top of the SoC.  I don't think that should make any difference, but the Foundation has *two* primary manufacturer/distributors that make boards with minor componentry differences.  They should still be completely compatible though.

Comment: You should try applying `hdmi_safe=1` in `config.txt` as [explained here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_safe) and if that works, apply the options it includes individually and pare them down until you have something satisfactory (since the hdmi_safe default is low resolution; note also I think options placed later in the file will override).  If it is a "minor componentry" issue it could boil down to `config_hdmi_boost` and/or `hdmi_force_hotplug`.  If this works please feel free to leave your own answer.

Comment: I have never updated the firmware once I configured the system (my RPIs are working without maintenance), so I assume this must be the reason. If I do that on the old RPi and clone SD card into the new RPi it should work, right?

Comment: I would just try sticking the card in rather than going through cloning to find it still doesn't work.  I would presume firmware updates are intended to remain backward compatible to the extent that they cover undocumented hardware upgrades -- I've never heard of someone having a problem with that.  Although to be paranoid, if you do have multiple cards, you might want to clone the old one, update that, see if still works on your old board, and test it on the new one (or else save a copy of everything in your current `/boot` directory just in case).

Comment: @goldilocks I've updated all the packages and the firmware (`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo rpi-update`). The SD card with updated system works perfectly on all the old boards, but still doesn't boot on the new ones. Is it possible that I'm lacking some crucial packages that are included in the new raspbian and are not installed when upgrading?

Comment: I don't know. TBH,  my first Pi is more than four years old, but the oldest OS installation that I use regularly is probably less than one; occasionally I just start them from scratch again because all my stuff is maintained via git and/or rsync repos (including configuration files, etc.) and I have scripts to install the packages I know I need.  IMO it's important to try and keep yourself independent of any particular machine or installation this way because figuring out the things you need to know to do that is easier than the alternative.

Comment: A lot of problems that could be solved can take more time than is worthwhile -- lifetimes worth of work have gone into all this stuff, and sometimes I have to to make a judgement call and decide I have to step away from something even if I think I might eventually get to the bottom of it, because I don't have multiple lifetimes and prefer not to spend 16 hours a day at a keyboard.  So if you know a new install works, it might be better to focus your time on how to simplify/automate setting one up easily, then you don't have to depend on keeping what you have working as is into eternity.

Comment: Put another way: Cloning an entire OS installation is easy, but it is not very dependable, which is why tools for replicating things in a more focused (and portable) way have undergone so much evolution -- VCS systems, containerization, things like *chef*, *puppet*, and *ansible*.  There are a lot of options.  Personally I stick with git, rsync, tar, and scripting, but that's just me.  In any case, try to think in terms of a collection of semi-independent pieces rather than one baroque "big picture".

Comment: I have one more idea I think may be worth checking out. If it doesn't work, I will take your advice and configure it from the ground up, but this time in a more modular fashion.